# Nxt: TCP, HTTP, or both

Tags: nxt

In the NXT documentation it says that the Peer protocol uses TCP.  But looking through the code all I see is HTTP.  Does NXT use HTTP or TCP for the Peer protocol?

Comment: IMO, NXT is out of topic here.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli Community consensus has been that other crypto-currencies are on-topic, see e.g. [A](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/15/5406), [B](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/89/5406), [C](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/335/5406). [tag:NXT] being very similar to Bitcoin in design makes it a decent fit here. Also, it already has almost seventy questions here. If you wish to weigh in on the discussion about the scope of the site, feel free to create a [meta] post.

Comment: Also see the first paragraph of our [tour] which states "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as e.g. Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, Zerocoin, Dogecoin, Ethereum, and NXT."

Answer (score 2):

I was able to answer my own question through the Nxt dev forum.

https://nxtforum.org/general/peer-protocol-tcp-or-http/msg181766/

Adding it  here for others that may have the same question:

Up to version 1.4 Nxt used HTTP for peer communication. Starting with version 1.5 they are moving to WebSocket for peer communication

Comment: [Link to the forum article](https://nxtforum.org/general/peer-protocol-tcp-or-http/)

Comment: Both HTTP and WebSocket protocols are built on top of TCP.

Comment: I'm well aware of how the protocol stack works.  But there is a difference in how an HTTP client and a TCP client work.  That was the purpose of my question - to determine what approach they were using for the client